# How to define and use macro in Mathjax?

Tags: require, mathjax

I often use vector operation, and normally vector is written by Bold font, e.g.

```
$$ \boldsymbol x = \boldsymbol a \times \boldsymbol b + \boldsymbol c $$
```

which is somehow too long, so I like to define some new commands \bx, \ba, \bb first,

```
$$ 
\newcommand{\bx}{\boldsymbol x} 
\newcommand{\ba}{\boldsymbol a} 
\newcommand{\bb}{\boldsymbol b}
\newcommand{\bc}{\boldsymbol c} 
$$
```

then above equation can be written shortly as:

```
$$ \bx = \ba \times \bb + \bc $$
```

---

Because I use these Bold fonts so often, I don't want to type them time by time, I plan to define them as macro in a file: boldfont.js , when I need to type vector, I just require boldfont.js.

I write file as follows (save the file as: /config/TeX/boldfont.js, other file (such as color.js) under the same directory):

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
 TeX: {
        Macros: {
            ba: '{\\boldsymbol a}',
            bb: '{\\boldsymbol b}',
            bc: '{\\boldsymbol c}',
            bd: '{\\boldsymbol d}',
            be: '{\\boldsymbol e}',
            bf: '{\\boldsymbol f}',
            bg: '{\\boldsymbol g}',
            bh: '{\\boldsymbol h}',
            bi: '{\\boldsymbol i}',
            bj: '{\\boldsymbol j}',
            bk: '{\\boldsymbol k}',
            bl: '{\\boldsymbol l}',
            bm: '{\\boldsymbol m}',
            bn: '{\\boldsymbol n}',
            bo: '{\\boldsymbol o}',
            bp: '{\\boldsymbol p}',
            bq: '{\\boldsymbol q}',
            br: '{\\boldsymbol r}',
            bs: '{\\boldsymbol s}',
            bt: '{\\boldsymbol t}',
            bu: '{\\boldsymbol u}',
            bv: '{\\boldsymbol v}',
            bw: '{\\boldsymbol w}',
            bx: '{\\boldsymbol x}',
            by: '{\\boldsymbol y}',
            bz: '{\\boldsymbol z}',
        }
    }
});
```

And I try to use the file (using \require command) as

```
$$ 
\require{boldfont} 
\bf=\bu+\bv-\bw
$$
```

But it doesn't work, what's wrong？ How to define macro and use it?

Help me, please.

[image]

Comment: Please post a snippet that reproduced the problem.

Comment: Thanks ,Peter. I attached screenshot, give me some hints.

Comment: A screenshot is not sufficient, I'm afraid. You'll need to post a reproducible example, ideally as a snippet. Random guess: have a look at https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/extension-writing.html

Answer (score 0):

The TeX configuration block is read when the TeX input jax is first loaded, so if you call `MathJax.Hub.Config()` after that, the changes you make will not be seen by the TeX input jax.  So any macros you add that way will not have an effect.

Instead you should use

```
MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Macro('bx', '\\boldsymbol{x}');
MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Macro('ba', '\\boldsymbol{a}');
...
```

If you have a macro that takes arguments, you can add a third parameter that is the number of arguments needed.  E.g.

```
MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Macro('bs', '\\boldsymbol{#1}', 1);
```

The file should be stored in the `MathJax/extensions/TeX` folder (not `MathJax/config/TeX`), and if you call it `boldfont.js`, then at the end of the file, you need to add the line

```
MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete('[MathJax]/extensions/TeX/boldfont.js');
```

With those changes, I think you should be able to get it to work.  If not, check your console log for messages, and also use

```
MathJax.Message.Log()
```

to see if there are any file-load failures listed.

(This is my answer from the [MathJax User's Forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/lbUox860onU/m3IsC2M-AwAJ) where this question was cross posted).